# ios merge text with image doesn't work with non-wetsern characters

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, uiimageview, utf-16

I'm trying to develop localized help files. It works great with western languages but is not displaying non-western characters (just outputs the image file). Same happens if text is encoded in utf-8 or utf-16
Don't like posting all this code but I just can't track down where the issue is.
Any help much appreciated!

```
    - (IBAction)segmentedControlChanged:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {
    UIImage *helpImage;
    NSArray *helpText;
    if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        helpImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"HelpImage.png"];
        helpText = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                     NSLocalizedString(@"Tab1 - sample text", nil), kHelpTextKeyString,
                     @"Arial", kHelpTextKeyFontName,
                     //@"Helvetica-Bold", kHelpTextKeyFontName,
                     [NSNumber numberWithInt:20], kHelpTextKeyFontSize,
                     [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor], kHelpTextKeyColor,
                     CGRectCreateDictionaryRepresentation(CGRectMake(30.0, 55.0, 200.0, 28.0)), kHelpTextKeyRect,
                     nil],
                    // CGRectCreateDictionaryRepresentation(CGRectMake(38.0, 55.0, 200.0, 28.0)), kHelpTextKeyRect,
                    //CGRectCreateDictionaryRepresentation(CGRectMake(30.0, 55.0, 200.0, 28.0)), kHelpTextKeyRect,

                    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                     [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      NSLocalizedString(@"sample text ", nil),
                      NSLocalizedString(@" ", nil),
                      NSLocalizedString(@"more sample text", nil),
                      nil], kHelpTextKeyString,
                     @"Helvetica-Light", kHelpTextKeyFontName,
                     [NSNumber numberWithInt:10], kHelpTextKeyFontSize,
                     [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor], kHelpTextKeyColor,
                     CGRectCreateDictionaryRepresentation(CGRectMake(10.0, 80.0, 200.0, 28.0)), kHelpTextKeyRect,
                     nil],
                    nil];
    }

    // display actual image
    [self displaySelectedHelpImage:helpImage withTextArray:helpText];
}


/

    / merge selected help image to text
    - (void)displaySelectedHelpImage:(UIImage *)orgImage withTextArray:(NSArray *)textArr {
        CGImageRef cgImage = [orgImage CGImage];
        int pixelsWide              = CGImageGetWidth(cgImage);
        int pixelsHigh              = CGImageGetHeight(cgImage);
        int bitsPerComponent        = CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(cgImage);//8; // fixed
        int bitsPerPixel            = CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(cgImage);//bitsPerComponent * numberOfCompnent;
        int bytesPerRow             = CGImageGetBytesPerRow(cgImage);//(pixelsWide * bitsPerPixel) // 8; // bytes
        int byteCount               = (bytesPerRow * pixelsHigh);
        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace  = CGImageGetColorSpace(cgImage);//CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    // Allocate data
    NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:byteCount];
    // Create a bitmap context
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate([data mutableBytes], pixelsWide, pixelsHigh, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast); //kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);//kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast); //kCGImageAlphaOnly);
    // Set the blend mode to copy to avoid any alteration of the source data or to invert to invert image
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeCopy);
    // Set alpha
    CGContextSetAlpha(context, 1.0);
    // Color image
    //CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1 ,1, 1, 1.0);
    //CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, pixelsWide, pixelsHigh));
    // Draw the image to extract the alpha channel
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, pixelsWide, pixelsHigh), cgImage);

    // add text to image
    // Changes the origin of the user coordinate system in a context
    //CGContextTranslateCTM (context, pixelsWide, pixelsHigh);
    // Rotate context upright
    //CGContextRotateCTM (context, -180. *  M_PI/180);
    for (NSDictionary *dic in textArr) {

        CGContextSelectFont (context,
                             //todo
                             [[dic objectForKey:kHelpTextKeyFontName] UTF8String],
                             [[dic objectForKey:kHelpTextKeyFontSize] intValue],
                             kCGEncodingMacRoman);
        CGContextSetCharacterSpacing (context, 2);
        CGContextSetTextDrawingMode (context, kCGTextFillStroke);

        CGColorRef color = (CGColorRef)[dic objectForKey:kHelpTextKeyColor];
        CGRect rect;
        CGRectMakeWithDictionaryRepresentation((CFDictionaryRef)[dic objectForKey:kHelpTextKeyRect], &rect);

        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color); 

        if ([[dic objectForKey:kHelpTextKeyString] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            for (NSString *str in [dic objectForKey:kHelpTextKeyString]) {
                CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context,
                                         rect.origin.x,
                                         pixelsHigh - rect.origin.y,
                                         [str cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]],
                                         [str length]);
                rect.origin.y += [[dic objectForKey:kHelpTextKeyFontSize] intValue];
            }
        } else {
            CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context,
                                     rect.origin.x,
                                     pixelsHigh - rect.origin.y,
                                     [[dic objectForKey:kHelpTextKeyString] cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]],
                                     [[dic objectForKey:kHelpTextKeyString] length]);
        }
    }

    // Now the alpha channel has been copied into our NSData object above, so discard the context and lets make an image mask.
    CGContextRelease(context);
    // Create a data provider for our data object (NSMutableData is tollfree bridged to CFMutableDataRef, which is compatible with CFDataRef)
    CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFMutableDataRef)data);
    // Create our new mask image with the same size as the original image
    //CGImageRef maskingImage = CGImageMaskCreate(pixelsWide, pixelsHigh, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, dataProvider, NULL, YES);

    CGImageRef finalImage = CGImageCreate(pixelsWide,
                                          pixelsHigh,
                                          bitsPerComponent,
                                          bitsPerPixel,
                                          bytesPerRow,
                                          colorSpace,
                                          kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault,
                                          dataProvider,
                                          NULL,
                                          YES,
                                          kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

    // And release the provider.
    CGDataProviderRelease(dataProvider);

    UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:finalImage];

    // remove old scroll view
    if (scrollView) {
        [scrollView removeFromSuperview];
    }

    // construct new scroll view and size according to image
    UIScrollView *tempScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:containerView.bounds];
    tempScrollView.contentSize = theImage.size; 
    scrollView = tempScrollView;

    // construct an image view (sized at zero) and assign the help image to it
    UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, theImage.size.width, 0.0)];
    [tempImageView setImage:theImage];

    // push image view to scrolle view and scroll view to container view
    [tempScrollView addSubview:tempImageView];
    [containerView addSubview:tempScrollView];

    // animate
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"ResizeImageView" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

    // recover actual image size through animation
    [tempImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, theImage.size.width, theImage.size.height)];

    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

    [UIView commitAnimations];- (IBAction)segmentedControlChanged:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {
    UIImage *helpImage;
    NSArray *helpText;
    if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        helpImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"HelpImage.png"];
        helpText = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                     NSLocalizedString(@"Tab1 - sample text", nil), kHelpTextKeyString,
                     @"Arial", kHelpTextKeyFontName,
                     //@"Helvetica-Bold", kHelpTextKeyFontName,
                     [NSNumber numberWithInt:20], kHelpTextKeyFontSize,
                     [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor], kHelpTextKeyColor,
                     CGRectCreateDictionaryRepresentation(CGRectMake(30.0, 55.0, 200.0, 28.0)), kHelpTextKeyRect,
                     nil],
                    // CGRectCreateDictionaryRepresentation(CGRectMake(38.0, 55.0, 200.0, 28.0)), kHelpTextKeyRect,
                    //CGRectCreateDictionaryRepresentation(CGRectMake(30.0, 55.0, 200.0, 28.0)), kHelpTextKeyRect,

                    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                     [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      NSLocalizedString(@"sample text ", nil),
                      NSLocalizedString(@" ", nil),
                      NSLocalizedString(@"more sample text", nil),
                      nil], kHelpTextKeyString,
                     @"Helvetica-Light", kHelpTextKeyFontName,
                     [NSNumber numberWithInt:10], kHelpTextKeyFontSize,
                     [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor], kHelpTextKeyColor,
                     CGRectCreateDictionaryRepresentation(CGRectMake(10.0, 80.0, 200.0, 28.0)), kHelpTextKeyRect,
                     nil],
                    nil];
    }

    // display actual image
    [self displaySelectedHelpImage:helpImage withTextArray:helpText];
}


// merge selected help image to text
- (void)displaySelectedHelpImage:(UIImage *)orgImage withTextArray:(NSArray *)textArr {
    CGImageRef cgImage = [orgImage CGImage];
    int pixelsWide              = CGImageGetWidth(cgImage);
    int pixelsHigh              = CGImageGetHeight(cgImage);
    int bitsPerComponent        = CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(cgImage);//8; // fixed
    int bitsPerPixel            = CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(cgImage);//bitsPerComponent * numberOfCompnent;
    int bytesPerRow             = CGImageGetBytesPerRow(cgImage);//(pixelsWide * bitsPerPixel) // 8; // bytes
    int byteCount               = (bytesPerRow * pixelsHigh);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace  = CGImageGetColorSpace(cgImage);//CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    // Allocate data
    NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:byteCount];
    // Create a bitmap context
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate([data mutableBytes], pixelsWide, pixelsHigh, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast); //kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);//kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast); //kCGImageAlphaOnly);
    // Set the blend mode to copy to avoid any alteration of the source data or to invert to invert image
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeCopy);
    // Set alpha
    CGContextSetAlpha(context, 1.0);
    // Color image
    //CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1 ,1, 1, 1.0);
    //CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, pixelsWide, pixelsHigh));
    // Draw the image to extract the alpha channel
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, pixelsWide, pixelsHigh), cgImage);

    // add text to image
    // Changes the origin of the user coordinate system in a context
    //CGContextTranslateCTM (context, pixelsWide, pixelsHigh);
    // Rotate context upright
    //CGContextRotateCTM (context, -180. *  M_PI/180);
    for (NSDictionary *dic in textArr) {

        CGContextSelectFont (context,
                             //todo
                             [[dic objectForKey:kHelpTextKeyFontName] UTF8String],
                             [[dic objectForKey:kHelpTextKeyFontSize] intValue],
                             kCGEncodingMacRoman);
        CGContextSetCharacterSpacing (context, 2);
        CGContextSetTextDrawingMode (context, kCGTextFillStroke);

        CGColorRef color = (CGColorRef)[dic objectForKey:kHelpTextKeyColor];
        CGRect rect;
        CGRectMakeWithDictionaryRepresentation((CFDictionaryRef)[dic objectForKey:kHelpTextKeyRect], &rect);

        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color); 

        if ([[dic objectForKey:kHelpTextKeyString] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            for (NSString *str in [dic objectForKey:kHelpTextKeyString]) {
                CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context,
                                         rect.origin.x,
                                         pixelsHigh - rect.origin.y,
                                         [str cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]],
                                         [str length]);
                rect.origin.y += [[dic objectForKey:kHelpTextKeyFontSize] intValue];
            }
        } else {
            CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context,
                                     rect.origin.x,
                                     pixelsHigh - rect.origin.y,
                                     [[dic objectForKey:kHelpTextKeyString] cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]],
                                     [[dic objectForKey:kHelpTextKeyString] length]);
        }
    }

    // Now the alpha channel has been copied into our NSData object above, so discard the context and lets make an image mask.
    CGContextRelease(context);
    // Create a data provider for our data object (NSMutableData is tollfree bridged to CFMutableDataRef, which is compatible with CFDataRef)
    CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFMutableDataRef)data);
    // Create our new mask image with the same size as the original image
    //CGImageRef maskingImage = CGImageMaskCreate(pixelsWide, pixelsHigh, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, dataProvider, NULL, YES);

    CGImageRef finalImage = CGImageCreate(pixelsWide,
                                          pixelsHigh,
                                          bitsPerComponent,
                                          bitsPerPixel,
                                          bytesPerRow,
                                          colorSpace,
                                          kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault,
                                          dataProvider,
                                          NULL,
                                          YES,
                                          kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

    // And release the provider.
    CGDataProviderRelease(dataProvider);

    UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:finalImage];

    // remove old scroll view
    if (scrollView) {
        [scrollView removeFromSuperview];
    }

    // construct new scroll view and size according to image
    UIScrollView *tempScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:containerView.bounds];
    tempScrollView.contentSize = theImage.size; 
    scrollView = tempScrollView;

    // construct an image view (sized at zero) and assign the help image to it
    UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, theImage.size.width, 0.0)];
    [tempImageView setImage:theImage];

    // push image view to scrolle view and scroll view to container view
    [tempScrollView addSubview:tempImageView];
    [containerView addSubview:tempScrollView];

    // animate
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"ResizeImageView" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

    // recover actual image size through animation
    [tempImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, theImage.size.width, theImage.size.height)];

    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're drawing text using `CGContextShowTextAtPoint`, which has poor support for non-ASCII text.

Similar issues: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275437/unicode-character-not-showing), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190005/iphone-using-cgcontextshowtextatpoint-to-draw-special-characters). [Apple's documentation explains the issue.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_text/dq_text.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH213-BBCHIIIF)

Use a higher-level API to draw the text, such as the methods in `UIKit/UIStringDrawing.h`, like `-[NSString drawAtPoint:withFont:]`.

Comment: Aha, that's really interesting. Will give it a go and let you know how I get on, many thanks.

Comment: Still, working on it but certainly appears will work well. Thanks!

Comment: For anyone facing this issue, it was solved by using the coretext foundation class.